# How do I update parent records in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, tree, parent

i've been working on this mlm (pyramid) project, I am done with all the visual pyramid system display etc. now I need to update all parent records of the client. here's my database table and binary tree of users :

[image: Database table and binary tree display]

As you can see i have id and parentid, now when i add new user under an id. i need to update all parents' left / right and commission. I am finding it very complicated.. cos I can't just update 1 row.. i need to update all its parent rows, may be doing loop or w.e. If anyone has done this before please help me how can i do this.

Comment: What are you updating the `right`, `left` and `commission` columns to when you're adding a user?

Comment: @Aaron: that's most likely for a binary compensation plan in multilevel marketing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_plan (which -imho- usally boils down to: two of the fields contain a rather small number while the third one may be increasing over time ;-) )

Comment: But you will not be able to know final three fields in advance and also the tree structure changes with each new entry. So you should move those three fields to another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods to maintain hierarchical data on a conventional DBMS such as MySQL. Adjacency List Model, Path Enumeration Model and Nested Set Model are some of them. I sugest reading [Joe Celko's Trees and hierarchies in SQL for smarties](http://books.google.com.tr/books/about/Joe_Celko_s_Trees_and_hierarchies_in_SQL.html?id=uw2lq2o4VbUC&redir_esc=y). There are also some good articles about managing hierarchical data in MySQL:

- [Hierarchical Data in MySQL: Easy and Fast](http://ferdychristant.com/blog//archive/DOMM-7QJPM7)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: An additional reference which you might find useful: http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures

Comment: thanks emre yazici, may be that's the best answer i can expect right now I will surely read it.

Comment: @San, can I ask what did you use to update the commission ? are you using Nested set model ?